# How to push multiple values to a chrome.storage.local array key?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm using the following code to set a key:value to the local storage:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"key": value}, null);
```

What can I do to add multiple values to the key "key"?

Comment: {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}, do you mean so?

Comment: @SkalárWag It would be more like, {"key1":[1,12,222,345]}, or something like that, I believe.

Comment: But how would I push a new value on the chrome local storage array, keeping the old ones.

Comment: get() method, then in the callback function you set the new pushed array.

Comment: But if I set it again, it will replace the current value, do you know how the code structure is to add a new value to the key, instead of reaplacing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First use the `get` method and then use `set` inside the `get` callback to add your new storage data as a key/value pair to the storage object returned from `get`. Example:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(cfg) {
  if(typeof(cfg["key"]) !== 'undefined' && cfg["key"] instanceof Array) { 
    cfg["key"].push("value");
  } else {
    cfg["key"] = ["value"];
  }
  chrome.storage.local.set(cfg); 
});
```

Comment: Got the following error "Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Comment: Yep, that's because the array that you are trying to push to does not exist yet. A check for array existence should be performed before attempting the push, see the updated answer!