# Adding New Element to Array in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm having the most difficult time with what should be an easy problem. I am writing a chrome extension that uses an array to store a list of words for the user. On startup I check how much time has elapsed so that I can add the proper amount of words to the array. I followed the code here [How to Push Values To Chrome Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270282/how-to-push-multiple-values-to-a-chrome-storage-local-array-key) like so:

```
function addToWords(url) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(function(cfg) {
    if(typeof(cfg["myWords"]) !== 'undefined' && cfg["myWords"] instanceof Array) { 
      cfg["myWords"].push(url);
    } 
    chrome.storage.local.set(cfg); 
  });
}
```

But no matter what I do and how many times I call this function I get only the last call of the function added to the array. So for example if this was my "myWords" array to start:

```
["dog"]
```

And I then called

```
addToWords("horse");
addToWords("bird");
addToWords("pig");
addToWords("cat");
```

I would be left with an array with two items, ["dog","cat"]. Is there something wrong with the code I'm not seeing? Thanks

EDIT: To anyone having the same problem AFTER going setting up their async callback methods, pay attention to storage.local and storage.sync!! The async wasn't working because I was setting local and checking sync in the console (which is why the new values weren't there). Thanks to everyone for your help. The async suggestions and using the same storage make it run flawlessly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extensions : cannot get back my stored datas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252654/chrome-extensions-cannot-get-back-my-stored-datas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you missing the `keys` of the items you want o get?

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions):

```
StorageArea.get(string or array of string or object keys, function callback)
```

You are getting `undefined` all the time, because you are missing the key:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('someKeyRelatedToMyValues', function(cfg){...})

chrome.storage.local.set({'someKeyRelatedToMyValues':cfg})
```

You should consider using a callback function also for the `set` method. If you need to execute code after storing the data and that code relies on that stored data, you will need to wait until the data is properly stored.

When you call the four `addToWords` in a row, they are not waiting for the set data. So you will probably need to add a callback to that too:

```
function addToWords(url, callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(function(cfg) {
       if(typeof(cfg["myWords"]) !== 'undefined' && cfg["myWords"] instanceof Array) { 
           cfg["myWords"].push(url);
       } 

       chrome.storage.local.set(cfg, callback); 
    });
}
```

---

```
addToWords("horse", function(){
    addToWords("bird", function(){
       addToWords("pig", function(){
          addToWords("cat", function(){
              //continue your code here
          });
       });
    });
 });
```

Looking at that....I'd surely go to an approach that stores an array instead of storing a single value.

Comment: there is also an issue with asynchronous.

Comment: Could the async be why it's not storing? Even with storing the key, like so it's still not working. Tried both chrome.storage.sync.set({'myWords':cfg["myWords"]}); and chrome.storage.sync.set({'myWords':cfg});

Comment: The first time you execute it, it will be undefined. (Since you have not stored yet). Have you considered that in previous code?

Comment: And yes, the `asynchronous` may cause problems, as updated.

Comment: So I've been debugging since everyone's help because with all the async callbacks I still couldn't get it to work. To anyone else who's had the problem after going through the trouble of getting the async set up make sure you're not using sync and local storage to compare values! I was setting with sync and checking local!! So focused on the difficult problems I missed the simple one. Thanks to everyone's help it's finally working.